# Trying to search files from user keyword in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

This code accepts user input and looks for a particular file the user can choose:

```
while [[ $reply != 2 ]]            
do 
    echo "1) Read from file"
    echo "2) exit"   
    read -p "Pick [1-2]" reply          
    case $reply in                       

        1) echo -e "\nSearching for file\n"
            read -p "Search key?" fileName
            
            if [[ -f $fileName ]]
            then
                while IFS= read -r line 
                do 
                    echo "$line"
                done < "$fileName"               
            else
                echo "$fileName - doesn't exist"
            fi                  
            ;;                  
        2)  echo -e "\nGoodbye!"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

And now, I'm trying to use this code and change it so that the user enters a keyword from a specific file and extract the information.
Ex: lines containing 'sales' from this sample file:

```
2233:charles harris     :g.m.       :sales          :12/12/52: 90000
9876:bill johnson       :director   :production     :03/12/50:130000
5678:robert dylan       :d.g.m.     :marketing      :04/19/43: 85000      
2365:john woodcock      :director   :personnel      :05/11/47:120000 
5423:barry wood         :chairman   :admin          :08/30/56:160000     
1006:gordon lightfoot   :director   :sales          :09/03/38:140000
```

What would be the best way of doing that in BASH?

Comment: What is not working or where are you stuck?

Comment: I have managed to search for files (this one: emp.lst) and display them. Now I am trying to enter a keyword from the file and display only those results...

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds some issues with the code.

Comment: To print the lines in a file that contain a keyword string use `grep -F -- "$keyword" "$fileName"`.

Comment: There are a few bugs in the code that prints the contents of `$fileName`.  Try it on the `test.txt` file produced by `printf 'line1\n-n\n-e\n-E\nline5\nline6' >test.txt`.  See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for details of how to reliably process a text file line-by-line with Bash code.  (Note that on Stackoverflow you will find many accepted and/or extravagantly upvoted answers on this topic that are subtly broken or completely broken.  There is bad code in many other places too.)

Comment: Since it's very slow compared to alternatives, it's best to avoid processing files line-by-line with pure Bash code.  In this case a much better option is simply: `cat -- "$fileName"`.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I've tried to add your piece of advice to my code, and I can't get it to work. I'm missing something obv. Can you show me how to do it pretty pls?

Comment: Why do you need a script around this at all? The command in @pjh:s comment does what you want.

Comment: Oh, just a school exercise. May not make sense in a real life context.