# Bash: The code I have opens the file chosen by a user. How can I add a second search for the user to search for keywords to find in that file?

Tags: linux, bash

This is the code I have started, but it's only doing the first part:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while [[ $userIn != 2 ]]
do 
    echo "1) Read file"
    echo "2) exit"
    
    read -p "Pick: " userIn
    
    case $userIn in 
        1) echo -e "Reading ..."
            read -p "Choose file: " fileName
            read -p "Enter Keyword: " keywd
            
            if [[ -f $fileName ]]
           
            then 
             #   exec 5< ${fileName}
                while IFS= read -r line
                do 
                    echo "$line"
                done < "$fileName"
            #    exec 5<&-
            else
                echo "$fileName - doesn't exist"
            fi
            ;;
        2) echo -e "\Goodbye!"
        ;;
        3) echo -e "\n???"
    esac
    
done
```

I have tried to add a grep in the 'if' statement, but that returned an error.
I also tried a elif, but that's not working either.
I'm sure there's an easy way of doing this, but I'm a newbie, I don't know much yet.
Anyway if you can help, I'd be very obliged.

Comment: What has changed since [Trying to search files from user keyword in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71366196/4154375)?

Comment: Please post the code, with a `grep`, that produces an error.  Please also provide precise details of the error that you see.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) might help you to find the cause of the error by yourself.  ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is an excellent tool for finding errors, bugs, and bad practices.)

Comment: Hi I tried Shellcheck, thx. I added the line:                           if [[ grep -F "$pattern" "$filename" ]] in the code above, but that's obviously not right...

Comment: Is this meant to be a production script or a toy problem? If this is meant to go into any kind of production system I would strongly urge you to change the paradigm to use script arguments rather than an interactive menu.

Comment: It's a school lab, I'm not yet a professional. I need to find a solution by using specific pre-defined ways

Comment: @MarioPelletier, strangely, I tried putting code with `if [[ grep -F "$pattern" "$filename" ]` into [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and it referred me to [SC1014 - Use `if cmd; then` ...](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1014), which explains exactly what the problem is, and how to fix it.  The example command that it uses is even a `grep` command.  Perhaps you used a different [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

Proposed solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ "$userinput" != 2 ]]
do
    echo "1) Read file"
    echo "2) Exit"

    read -r -p "Pick: " userinput

    case "$userinput" in
        1)
            read -r -p "Choose file: " filename
            read -r -p "Enter keyword: " keyword

            if [[ -f "$filename" ]]
            then
                if grepresult=$(grep -w "$keyword" "$filename")
                then
                    echo -e "\n$grepresult\n"
                else
                    echo -e "\n$keyword not found in file $filename.\n"
                fi
            else
                echo -e "\n$filename - does not exist.\n"
            fi
            ;;
        2)
            echo -e "\nGoodbye!"
            ;;
        *)
            echo -e "\n???"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Modifications from your code:

- I added `-r` to each of your `read` statements.
- All variables are double-quoted when used.
- `grep` was used to extract line(s) with the desired keyword.
- `grep -w` was used to extract only whole words.  I.e. if the keyword is "local" it will not match "localhost" nor "localise".
- The `if` checks the return status of the `grep` command.  If it found something, the return status will be 0, and execute the `if` part.  Otherwise, it will execute the `else` part.
- `grepresult` is used to store the results and display them in the `if`.  This is done to avoid running `grep` twice (once to see if the keyword is in the file, another one to display the results).
- For readability, I added `\n` here and there to split the output from the "menu".

Comment: Finally someone could see through what I was looking for! Thanks, it works fine, and it's not miles away from what I was trying. A question: why don't I need these lines anymore ? # while IFS= read -r line 
                #do 
                #    echo "$line"
                # done < "$fileName"   I thought IFS was necessary to read the file. And why couldn't I use $line as a variable?? I'll look on it longer tomorrow, but at least now I can sleep. Thank you .

Comment: Hi Mario.  Your `while` reads the file line per line to check if each line contains the keyword.  For some languages, this is the only way to go.  But in `bash`, you want to use the existing utilities that unix/linux provides you.  Here, that is `grep`.  It does what you require, for the entire file.  And it is coded for you (in C), is faster, secure and provides "advanced" capabilities (like pattern matching, counts, ...).  *Note* if the answer matches your requirement, you can accept it via the checkmark on the left of the answer.